# class prototype in c++ related query

Tags: c++

how to give a prototype for class in c++ if i want to declare after main()?
i wrote the following code fragment. i have refered to material available on cplusplus.com, i tried googling it but could not find anything useful.i by mistake the declared the class below main , but then i realised that i had not given a prototype for it and thus my program could not run.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    student s;
    s.show();

    getch();
}

class student
{
    int age;
    public:
    void show();
};

void student::show()
{
    age = 5;
    cout << age;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I use a forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: `void main` is invalid C++. I’m surprised your compiler lets you do that. Dial up the warning level.

Comment: i am using the compiler  turbo c++, in that it is valid to use void main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `student` must be a *complete* type if you write `student s;`. A forward declaration is therefore not sufficient.

The obvious solution is to write the class declaration in a file called `student.h` and `#include` that at the top of the file that defines `main()`.

Comment: i removed the function show from my program and then the program worked why so??

Comment: *That* is interesting. I think you should post that as a new question, perhaps under the title "why does this code compile and run despite my declaring an automatic instance of an incomplete type". And mention which compiler you're using.